# Drupal unable to install Facebook Photo Sync module

Tags: php, drupal, drupal-7, drupal-6

i am trying to install the " Facebook Photo Sync " module, But i am always getting this below error

> Error message Facebook PHP SDK library missing, please view the
>   README.txt for installation instructions.

Note: as per readme instruction i pasted the Facebook-PHP-SDK libraries in to site/all/module/libraries/facebook-php-sdk.

For your reference i attached screen shot.

[image: pic 1] 
[image: pic 2]

Answer (score 2, accepted):

@Bharanikumar

Make sure you had followed this steps to use the Facebook PHP SDK library

You will need:

With Drupal 7 (`drupal.org/project/drupal`) installed
Drupal for Facebook -module (`drupal.org/project/fb`)
PHP SDK for the Facebook API (`github.com/facebook/php-sdk`)
Facebook Account

**Step 1: Downloading all the necessary files**

1. Install Drupal 7 and set it up.
2. Download "Drupal for Facebook" -module
3. Go to "PHP SDK for the Facebook API"-page on GitHub and download the latest PHP SDK for Facebook.
4. Extract the files to "sites/all/libraries/facebook-php-sdk"

**Step 2: Creating a new Facebook Application**

1. Go to Facebook Developers (`developers.facebook.com/apps`) page and select "Create new application"
2. Write your "App Display Name" and accept the "Facebook Platform Policies"
3. Keep the page open, we will need the APP ID & Secret later. You can also setup the icon for the Application on this page. Users when see it when logging in on your website

**Step 3: Enabling the Facebook module**

1. Login as Admin to your Drupal site and go to "Modules" (admin/modules)
2. Under "Drupal for Facebook"-fieldset, choose "Facebook API", "Facebook App" and "Facebook Connect" and click "Save".
3. Go to "Drupal for Facebook"-settings (admin/structure/fb) and click "Add App"
4. On "Label", write a name for this App, like "fblogin1". On "Facebook App ID" and "Secret" write the info from the Facebook page before.
5. Select "Primary" under "Facebook Connect" and click "Save".